# Selenium WebDriver won't return correct title of Google results page

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

I'm practicing with the Cucumber automation framework so I can use it for a project at work. I'm using Selenium WebDriver to interact with the browser. Right now I'm just testing that a Google search does in fact return correct results. My feature file is here:

```
Feature: Google

    Scenario: Google search
        Given I am on the Google home page
        When I search for "horse"
        Then the results should relate to "horse"
```

This is my Java class with the step definitions:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.junit.Assert;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class StepDefinitions {

    WebDriver driver = null;

    @Given("^I am on the Google home page$")
        public void i_am_on_the_Google_home_page() throws Throwable {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @When("^I search for \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_search_for(String query) throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(query);
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    }

    @Then("^the results should relate to \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void the_results_should_relate_to(String result) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains(result));
    }
 }
```

To test that it does return related results, I'm just asserting that the page title contains the search query. Right now, it's failing the last step because `driver.getTitle()` is returning "Google", and not the expected "horse - Google Search".

I'm not sure why it's doing this. I've checked the HTML of the results page, and the title is what I expected it to be. But Selenium is not returning the right result. Can someone explain to me why and how I can fix it?

Comment: Is it returning the title of the previous page? It may be returning the page title before the page transition is completed. Sorry, I don't know Cucumber so I can't provide code but you might try inserting a wait and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer:

Probably you need to add some wait time before asserting the page title, because some times driver actions are pretty quick, that may cause assertion failures

```
@Then("^the results should relate to \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void the_results_should_relate_to(String result) throws Throwable {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("some element in page"))));
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().contains(result));
    }
```

Comment: That `.implicitlyWait()` isn't doing what you seem to think it does. That line sets a global wait time... it does NOT wait for up to 10 seconds only in that one location. http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits.

Comment: I'm not familar with Cucumber but in Java/C#, what you want is a WebDriverWait. I found a page referencing possible solutions in Cucumber. http://www.seleniumframework.com/cucumber-jvm-3/waits-and-synchronization/

Comment: I've updated my answer.. what i meant was giving some wait time before asserting page title

Comment: The WebDriverWait is the proper way to do this.... I would remove the Thread.sleep() option because that is not a good practice.